# how to avoid full table scan when joining on one foreign key

Tags: mysql

how to avoid full table scan when joining on one foreign in key below is my sql query when i use explain select it show the query is scanning all the table even with a where clause

```
SELECT  message_recipients.id, message_recipients.user_type,
COALESCE(guardians.firstname, students.firstname)
    FROM  message_recipients
    LEFT JOIN  students  ON message_recipients.user_id = students.student_id
    LEFT JOIN  guardians  ON message_recipients.user_id = guardians.guardian_id
    WHERE  message_recipients.message_id = 2
```

Also i added index on the message_id column still the same here below is the image of the explain select may be am reading it wrong

[image]

the total rows in the table is 8 but the `message_id = 2` is just 6 rows and if you check the image you can see its scanning all the 8 rows which is not suppose to be the big question is how do i optimize this to avoid full table scan thanks

Comment: if you have very few rows in the table, it can decide it isn't worth using an index.  worry more about queries that are actually slow, not full table scans in fast queries.

Comment: this table has the potential of growing very large the table will be holding larger record up to millions

Comment: then you need to work with that much data to try it out :)

Comment: as i keep adding more records it shows the query is scanning all the rows

Comment: to encourage people to look at this more closely, I suggest you edit your question to add (as text, not images) output of `show create table yourtablename` for all tables in the query, and output of explain as text, not an image, and reformat your query to not be all on one line so it's easier to read

Comment: Punctuate "that that is is that that is not is not is not that it it is".  Then I may try to read your unpunctuated Question.

Comment: very funny I don't understand a word from your comment

Comment: well I did not understand your first paragraph

Answer (score 0):

One way to avoid a full scan is to use clustered queries with a "with" clause like this:

```
WITH TB_A AS (
    SELEC
        A.*
    FROM 
        some_table A
    WHERE 
        A.field_1 = 'some condition to filter first table'
)
, TB_B AS (
    SELECT 
        B.*
    FROM 
        other_table B
    WHERE 
        B.field_2 = 'some condition to filter second table if you need that too'
)
SELECT 
    A.*
    , B.*
FROM 
    TB_A A 
INNER JOIN 
    TB_B B
    ON A.field_1 = B.field_1 --Running without full scan on join and much faster
;
```

;D

Comment: Adding indexes solve it and making test with larger record

Answer (score 0):

A `FOREIGN KEY` creates an `INDEX`, but that `INDEX` may not be optimal.  See if these 'composit' indexes are better:

```
message_recipients:  INDEX(message_id, user_id,  id, user_type)
guardians:  INDEX(guardian_id,  firstname)
students:   INDEX(student_id,   firstname)
```

When adding a composite index, DROP index(es) with the same leading columns.
That is, when you have both INDEX(a) and INDEX(a,b), toss the former.

Comment: I only add index to the message_id and i got the expected result testing with little data in the table was misleading also adding more data to the table and adding index to the message_id gave the expected result

Comment: @Sunny - There is no need to add an index twice.  It will continually be updated.